# Why do some people consider population and some population density in SIR models?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

While learning about SIR models, I came across two versions and both have S+I+R=N where N is the total population. [One version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1P8i.jpg) in which the right hand side of the equations have S*I:

[image]

and the [other version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFN7v.png) in which they consider S*I/N:

[image]

My question is what is the difference between them? When to use which? My other question is regarding the latter version: why is only I divided by N and not S?

Comment: Just comes down to the way you group units; the second way $\beta$ and $\mu$ have the same units, in the first they have different units.

Comment: given a modeling situation, how do you know which one to use?

Comment: Either will work, it's just a matter of notation.

Comment: There is an ongoing debate regarding this topic in the mathematical modeling world. The issue is related to the interpretation of the model parameters. You will find this well-cited article useful: Begon, Michael, Malcolm Bennett, Roger G. Bowers, Nigel P. French, S. M. Hazel, and Joseph Turner. "A clarification of transmission terms in host-microparasite models: numbers, densities and areas." Epidemiology & Infection 129, no. 1 (2002): 147-153.